# Swap the first 8 bits and the last 8 bits of 16-bit value

Tags: c, bit

I tried to swap the first 8 bits and the last 8 bits of 16-bit value. For example, 00000001 11001100 becomes 11001100 00000001; Well I dont know how to implement it though. I tried different ways but it does not work....Any help will appreciated. Sorry if this question is simple. I just started learning bits thing. Thank u.I have a function:

```
unsigned short swap_bytes(unsigned short x) {

}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried *any* ways :-(

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx

Comment: typedef union mini
{
    unsigned char b[2]; 
    unsigned short s;
} micro;

Comment: unsigned short swap_bytes(unsigned short x) {
micro y;
    y.s = b;
    unsigned char tmp = y.b[0];
    y.b[0] = y.b[1];
    y.b[1] = tmp;
    return y.s;

}

Comment: But it does not work still!!!!!

Comment: If you are providing coding attempts, please edit your question and add them there, properly formatted. Code samples as comments are difficult to read, and won't get the attention they need.

Comment: I tried the code you showed in your comments and it worked fine. So your problem description needs to be specific about (a) what does your code look like, and (b) what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned short swap_bytes(unsigned short x) {
    unsigned short result;
    result = (x >> 8) | (x << 8);

    return result;
}
```

valter

Comment: Or just:  `return (x >> 8) | (x << 8);`

Comment: @mbratch Yes indeed, but i wanted to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the value is exactly 16 bits.

```
unsigned short swap_bytes(unsigned short x) 
{
    unsigned short bitmask = 0x00FF;
    unsigned short temp = x & bitmask;
    x = x >> 8;
    temp = temp << 8;
    x = x | temp;
    return x;
}
```

How it works:

1. bitmask = 0x00FF makes bitmask a value with 8 leading zero bits and then 8 trailing 1s.
2. temp = x & bitmask makes temp a value with 8 leading zero bits, and then the 8 bits identical to the last 8 bits of x.
3. x = x >> 8 shifts the leftmost (most significant) 8 bits of x to the right, replacing them with 0s.
4. temp = temp << 8 shifts the rightmost 8 bits of temp to the left, replacing them with 0s.
5. x = x | temp combines the last 8 bits of x (which were the first 8 bits of x before shifting), with the first 8 bits of temp (which were the last 8 bits of x before shifting).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    typedef union{
        unsigned char arr[2];
        short s;
    }SwapBit;

    SwapBit sb;
    sb.s = 100;

    cout<<bitset<16>(sb.s)<<endl;
    std::swap(sb.arr[0], sb.arr[1]);

    cout<<bitset<16>(sb.s)<<endl;
}
```

The result is:

```
0000000001100100
0110010000000000
```

Comment: The OP's tags indicate he's using C, not C++.